# What is exactly happening when we run Python manage.py runserver

Tags: python

Python manage.py runserver

after that
 which is executed first views.py or models.py or urls.py and what is the use of admin.py

Comment: You should be able to answer that questions by adding some `print` statements and reading the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely the `urls.py` file is executed first. Since the Django application will not know what to do without loading the endpoints, it executes the `urls.py` file to read all the rules for endpoints. After that, Django project is served. Now, if you go to a Django admin page in your browser, Django runs `admin.py` (assuming you  you meant the admin controller). If you load your own URLs, Django goes to your `views.py` then to `models.py`.

Answer (score 0):

I explain what I know, Suppose you are running the Django server. you requested the Django server from the browser, The first Django request goes to urls.py -> views.py -> models.py.